# Memory leak with iPython Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm facing a memory leak issue with ipython in Jupyter Notebook while loading large data to pandas. 10GB of data consuming 65GB of RAM.

According to [#issue642](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/642) the problem got resolved after upgrading jsonschema2.4 to jsonschema2.5.1. 
But I'm currently using Anaconda, python3.6.3 along with jsonschema2.6.0 and still experiencing the memory leak.

Please let me know if there is any other know reason for this issue, which I'm not aware.

Comment: could you share the error meg pls?

Comment: I didn't receive any error. The data got loaded successfully. but for 1GB its consuming 13GB and 10GB  it's around 65GB and so on.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "10 GB of data"? How is that measured?